# Flutter WebView doesn't work on canvas for web

Tags: flutter, dart, web, canvas

I am building a cross platform application for web, android and mobile using WebView feature but I want to use the canvas implementation but the WebView doesn't work in canvas what should be done.

Comment: did you solve this problem?

Comment: Yes check the answer below

Answer (score 2):

In fact you can use the HtmlElementView

Heres an example

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  // ignore: undefined_prefixed_name
  ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory(
      'hello-html',
      (int viewId) => IFrameElement()
        ..width = '640'
        ..height = '360'
        ..src = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/xg4S67ZvsRs'
        ..style.border = 'none');

  runApp( Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(25),
        child: SizedBox(
          width: 640,
          height: 360,
          child: HtmlElementView(viewType: 'hello-html'),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Check it out here:

```
https://codepen.io/riccio85/pen/wvMeaMe
```